# Anaconda installing pythonnet

Tags: python, anaconda, package, python.net, pythonnet

Can someone help me with the error I'm getting when I try to install pythonnet in Anaconda. On the website it is stated that I just need to enter`conda install -c pythonnet pythonnet` or through pip `pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pythonnet/simple pythonnet` and both doesn't work. When I'm trying to do it with anaconda it says `PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:  - pythonnet` and when I do it with pip it says `failed with error code 1`. It's not my first time installing packeges in anaconda and normally it always worked.

Comment: What website? What OS?

Comment: URL: https://anaconda.org/pythonnet/pythonnet

Comment: OS: macOS highSierra 10.13.1

Comment: Right, so if you look at the files for that package, you can see that they're only available for windows

Comment: @FabienMorgan have a look at this: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Troubleshooting-on-Windows,-Linux,-and-OSX#osx-notes

Comment: basically you need mono installed in osx first